# How to display Stack Frames that contain function variables in Visual Studio (2008), C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stack-frame

Is there a way to configure visual studio (2008) to visualize function variables in each stack frame?  I can see the call stack just fine with the function parameters but was wondering if there is a way to see the variables in the function as well. This would be especially helpful for inspecting the stack content and learning how recursive function calls work. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Debug + Windows + Locals shows you all the local variables in the active stack frame.

[image]

Comment: And if you want to see the Locals in previous stack frames, just double-click on the stack frame in the Call Stack window, and the Locals window will change to show them.  (You can have Call Stack and Locals in different windows; they don't need to all be in a single window with tabs.)